# How to specify a generic type of the variable?

Tags: scala, generics, type-inference

In the following code I would like to use `map` with `breakOut` and to specify the result should be `IndexedSeq`, but I do not want to provide the type of the sequence elements, I want the compiler to deduce it. I can write my own helper generic function (`asIndexedSeq` below) which does the job, but I think I am perhaps missing some obvious more "native" way how to to this.

```
val m = Map("a"->1, "b"->2)

implicit class CastAsIndexedSeq[T](s: IndexedSeq[T]) {
  def asIndexedSeq = s
}

val t1 = m.map(_._1 + ":")(collection.breakOut).asIndexedSeq
val t2: IndexedSeq[String]= m.map(_._1 + ":")(collection.breakOut) // works, but I want String to be deduced
val t4: IndexedSeq[_] = m.map(_._1 + ":")(collection.breakOut) // almost works, but static type is lost
val t4: IndexedSeq[_] = m.map(_._1 + ":").toIndexedSeq // intermediate collection created, I prefer breakOut
val t3: IndexedSeq = m.map(_._1 + ":")(collection.breakOut) // compile error
```

Is there some more concise way?